# Is return none necessary if not used does it break the code?

Tags: python

Is return none necessary?
if not used what will happen does it keep returning variables and commands etc?
thank you for the help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [return, return None, and no return at all?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15300550/return-return-none-and-no-return-at-all)

Comment: Related: [Is there a reason python functions should always return some value?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66259318/2745495)

Comment: *return None* is not necessary. *return* without an expression will return None. If a function ends without an explicit *return* then it will implicitly return None. No idea what you mean by "returning ... commands"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In python, if you do not return anything, it will automatically (implicitly) return `None`.

You can test that by making a function like

```
def fun():
    pass
```

Then you can print the output of that function

```
print(fun())
```

And you will see that it will output `None`. Thus, it is not a must to return `None`.

Answer (score 1):

No, return statements are not necessary in a Python function.

If there is no return statement, Python will **implicitly** return none when it reaches the end of the function.

Comment: An explicit `return` is sometimes needed for example, a function is doing a loop to search for a value and then raising an Exception if the loop did not find any. For that case, if you did find a value, you can break out of the loop by `return`-ing,